# Positioning labels of all nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to set the labels of all nodes. I can do that for every node (label) separately:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={red}]
\node[draw, label=right:A label] (anode) {A node};
\node[draw, right=2cm of anode, label=right:Another label] {Another node};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But that is very tedious. How can I set all labels to be right of nodes like the color for all nodes?

Comment: [`label position=right`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/label:position)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to set a global style, e.g. `rlabel`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  rlabel/.style = {label={right:#1}},
  every label/.style={red},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rlabel=A label] (anode) {A node};
  \node[draw, right=2cm of anode, rlabel=Another label] {Another node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]